# json_decode returns NULL on a json_encod-ed string

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have this bit of code:

```
<?php $arr= array(
array
(
    'name'        => 'Sony PS4',  
    'quantity'    => '1', 
    'unit_price'  => '$250.00'
),
array
(
    'name'        => 'XBox 360', 
    'quantity'    => '1', 
    'unit_price'  => '$200.00'
));?>
```

Then I have this Ajax-request line

```
<?php $encoded_json = json_encode($arr); echo '<script>'; echo 'var encodedStr = "'. $encoded_json. '"'; echo 'var params = "encodedValue=" + encodedStr'; //Ajax GET request with 'params' variable goes here, </script>';?>
```

And here's the ajax-request-processing line:

```
<?php $encoded_value = $_GET['encodedValue']; json_decode($encoded_value); //this gives me null, rather than the original encoded array ?>
```

Is there something not right with my code? How do I get back my original array? Any pointers in the right direction, please.

Comment: If the encoded value is coming from a GET request, it could have been URL encoded. Try passing it through `urldecode` and if that doesn't work please echo that value and included it above.

Comment: what is that? what are you trying to do? just directly put `encodedStr` inside `data:` if this is jquery, you don't need to quote it, is an object already once echoed

Comment: Are you sure that this is a copy and past of the code? The code created by `var encodedStr = "'. $encoded_json. '">`  will create a syntax error.

Comment: Perhaps you could display the obtained string somewhere so you can see what it actually contains?

Comment: @t.niese, yes, it is a copy and paste of the code. I don't see the line you talked about could cause a syntax error. I am using PHP to echo javascript, and concatenation is valid, right? vinntec, when I displayed the obtained string in Javascript, I get [object Object]

Comment: Ah, that's already a step forwards. You're not getting what you thought you would: the actual JSON string.

Comment: The javascript code created by the php code is invalid. (The 5th line of your `Then I have this Ajax-request line` code)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to send the JSON as a string to PHP. There are plenty of ways of doing this like JSON.stringify.
Then you should check if there is an actual JSON formatted string to decode.
Then check what value is returned from the json_decode function, if the value is not true, then check the error with [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) function

```
$encoded_value = $_GET['encodedValue']; 
if (!$encoded_value) { die('No value to parse'); }
$result = json_decode($encoded_value); 
if (!$result) { die(json_last_error()); }
```

Comment: The json_encode-d string is seen by javascript as [object Object]. I have a feeling that's where the issue is coming from. How to make PHP understand javascript's [object Object]

Comment: You need to send the JSON as a string to PHP. There are plenty of ways of doing this like JSON.stringify

Comment: @ Laurynas Mališauskas, thank you. That did it. Thank you sooo much. You need to re-post this as an answer, rather than a comment, so I can mark it as the accepted answer. would you?